# Pandas drop first n Rows per column id

Tags: python, pandas

Example DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2200, 3300, 50), index=[np.random.randint(0,6, 50)] ,columns=list('A'))
```

Below is a sample of what the data would look like

```
    A
5  2393
4  2421
0  3038
5  2914
4  2559
4  2314
5  3006
3  2553
0  2642
3  2441
3  2512
0  2412
```

What I would like to do is drop the first n (lets use 2 for this example) records of index.  So from the previous data example it would become...

```
    A
4  2314
5  3006
3  2512
0  2412
```

Any guidance here would be appreciated. I haven't been able to get anything to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `tail` with `-2`

```
s.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=-2)

      A
0  2412
3  2512
4  2314
5  3006
```

To really nail it down

```
s.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=-2)

      A
5  3006
4  2314
0  2412
3  2512
```

Comment: *Much* better than what I was trying to do!

Comment: Worked really well thank you.  I tweaked it a little to drop 3 records and use a column instead of index.

              
df = df.groupby('SN', group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.tail, n=-3)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want a new dataframe that has the first `n` rows of your dataframe removed. If that's what you want, I would reset the index, then drop based on pandas' default index, then put the original index back. Here's how you might do that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(2200, 3300, 50), 
                  index=np.random.randint(0,6, 50),
                  columns=list('A'))
n = 5
print(df.head(n * 2))
df_new = df.reset_index().drop(range(n)).set_index('index')
print(df_new.head(n))
```